# Bash removing files from directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove files from a test directory with while loop. There are 8 files total in my test directory. I keep getting the error `rm: cannot remove file1: No such file or directory` repeating through `file8`. Here is what I have... Where am I going wrong with this and how can I correct it?

```
var=(`ls ~/Files/Test`)

x=${#var[@]}
i=0

while [ $i -lt $x ] ; do
    rm "${var[$i]}"
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: You should have a look at the Bash Wiki entry on [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Oh, and either accept John1k's answer, or provide clarification in your question as to what the heck you're trying to achieve by scripting something that is a natural one-liner. :-)

Comment: Your file names don't have a leading directory name.  Please don't use `ls` to get a list of files, use globing  (wildcards, filename expansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that script, run:

```
rm ~/Files/Test/*
```

This will delete all files in your test directory and it will work correctly even if the file names contains spaces, tabs, or other difficult characters.

If, for some strange reason, you really really want a loop, then use:

```
for fname in ~/Files/Test/*
do
    rm "$fname"
done
```

This will also work correctly even with difficult file names.

Comment: Yeah I know there are easier ways... I was just trying to do it one at a time with the while loop